# How to have and use Shared Memory in Apache Storm Bolt?

Tags: apache, apache-storm

I am making a data sampling system in Storm.
I am having a problem in bolts.
My system bolts share memory (it is sample bucket) because data is stored in sample.
How can I use Shared Memory in Apache Storm Bolt?

For example,

[image: Sampling Bolts]